# How to use MockClassLoader?

Tags: java, junit, powermock

I am trying to test a class, where it has some tightly coupled dependencies. I am thinking to use MockClassLoader in PowerMock to mock the class definition of the dependency itself.

Any idea of how to use MockClassLoader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think MockClassLoader is supposed to be used directly in test code, it looks much more like a PowerMock implementation detail. Instead please take a look at PowerMock policies. A mock policy implementation can for example suppress some methods, suppress static initializers or intercept method calls on per-class basis. 
Suppose you have a tightly coupled code like this:

```
public class Holder {    
   private final DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();

   public DataObject getData() {
     return dataObject;
   }
}
```

One may create a policy to control the DataObjects:

```
public class MyMockPolicy implements PowerMockPolicy {

  public void applyClassLoadingPolicy(MockPolicyClassLoadingSettings settings) {
    settings.addFullyQualifiedNamesOfClassesToLoadByMockClassloader(Holder.class.getName());
  }

  public void applyInterceptionPolicy(MockPolicyInterceptionSettings settings) {
    Method getDataMethod = Whitebox.getMethod(Holder.class);
    DataObject dataObject = new DataObject(); //custom object
    settings.addSubtituteReturnValue(getDataMethod, dataObject);      
  }
```

}

and apply it with annotation

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@MockPolicy(MyMockPolicy.class)
public class DependencyUserTest {
  // test methods
}
```

Comment: Ok, great. Can I make use of it, to create a custom dataObject. But, to make sure, I cannot have a public accessor method, the business logic inside class will be using the dataObject directly.